# can't build and run app in docker compose. Task 'bootRun' not found in root project 'gradle'

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose

Spring Boot. I build and run project by Gradle.

```
gradlew bootRun
```

It's success build and run.
Nice.

Now I want to build and run by Docker compose.
Here my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8
FROM gradle
RUN gradle wrapper
RUN ./gradlew bootRun
ADD build/libs/eshop-1.0.0.jar eshop-1.0.0.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "eshop-1.0.0.jar"]
```

In docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

    services:
      server:
        build: .
        command: java -jar build/libs/eshop-1.0.0.jar
        ports:
          - 8090:8090
```

Now in Docker's tool run command like this:

```
$ docker-compose build
Building server
Step 1/6 : FROM openjdk:8
 ---> 8c6851b1fc09
Step 2/6 : FROM gradle
 ---> 1fcd09a6bb3b
Step 3/6 : RUN gradle wrapper
 ---> Using cache
 ---> acf242fa68db
Step 4/6 : RUN ./gradlew bootRun
 ---> Running in 8c7c62db19f9
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.2-bin.zip
.........10%.........20%.........30%..........40%.........50%.........60%..........70%.........80%.........90%..........100%

Welcome to Gradle 6.2!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Dependency checksum and signature verification
 - Documentation links in deprecation messages
 - Shareable read-only dependency cache

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'bootRun' not found in root project 'gradle'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 10s
ERROR: Service 'server' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c ./gradlew bootRun' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

So why I get error?

Comment: For bootRun to work, you application’s source code would have to be in the container. I can’t see anything in your Dockerfile that adds it. It would be more conventional to build your app outside the container and then add its fat jar or its classes and dependencies to the container. What is your reason for executing bootRun inside the container?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I added my answer

Comment: FWIW, Gradle/Spring Boot version incompatiblity also causes this. While unrelated directly to OP's case, I've had this error while trying to use Gradle 8.x with Spring Boot <= 2.6.4 ; bumping Spring Boot to 2.6.5 (or higher) solved this for me.

Answer (score 0):

I need to start my app on client machine with minimal steps.

this work for me.

Docfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD build/libs/myapps-1.0.0.jar myapps-1.0.0.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "myapps-1.0.0.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
 version: "3"

services:
  server:
    image: my_login/my_apps:1.0.0
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8090:8090
```

and now in Docker terminal:

In Project's folder:

```
     1. Create Dockerfile
     2. Create docker-compose.yml
     3. docker-compose build
     4. push image to repo:
        docker tag myapp my_login/myapp:1.0.0
        docker login -u "my_login" -p "some_my_pass" docker.io
        docker push my_login/eshop:myapp


 In some empty folder (in client machine):

 5. Pull from repo
    docker-compose pull
 6. start app by docker compose
    docker-compose up
 7. open web page on `localhost:8090`
```

and now it's work. Nice.

So the client need only to has my `docker-compose.yml` file and run two commands:

```
docker-compose pull
```

and

```
docker-compose up
```

Is it correct way to work with docker compose?

Answer (score 0):

Open build.gradle file (found in the root folder of the project) and ensure the following plugins exist in the file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.7.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}
```

P.S.: Plugin versions might defer.

(I had a similar issue, I cross-checked with properly working gradle files. Found two plugins missing in build.gradle of my project)